# Регулярные выражения с ограничением

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Работаю в PHP. Нужно заменить все ссылки, в которых присутствует расширение jpg, png и т.д. Делаю так:

```
$row["message"] = preg_replace('/<a\shref=\"(.+?[jpeg|jpg|png])\"\starget=\"_blank\">(.+?)<\/a>/is', '<a data-fancybox="gallery" href="$1"><img src="$1" alt="" class="tmp_class"></a>', $row["message"]);
```

Для тестирования следующая строка:

```
<p>С этой формы приходят заявки <a href="https://site.com/lack_tech.php">https://site.com/lack_tech.php</a></p>
<p>Или что ты имеешь ввиду?</p>
<div class="attachment_files_message"> 
   <p>Прикреплённые файлы:</p>
   <a href="http://site.com/public/uploads/kylticket/2670/Screenshot_1.png" target="_blank">Screenshot_1.png</a>
</div>
```

То есть нужно заменить вторую ссылку, а по моему коду, заменяется все что между началом ссылки `<a href="....` и до самого последнего концевого тега `</a>`

Comment: `[jpeg|jpg|png]` = `[jegnp|]`. Замените `\"(.+?[jpeg|jpg|png])\"` на `"([^"]*(?:jpe?g|png))"`. А лучше сначала распарсить с помощью DOM, тогда всё будет проще.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew спасибо, Ваше решение помогло, публикуйте ответ полноценный...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Шаблон `[jpeg|jpg|png]` идентичен `[jegnp|]`, так как `[...]` — это символьный класс, который находит 1 символ из указанных в классе. Кроме того, `.+?` может захватить слишком много текста, так как точка находит любой символ.

Если заменить `\"(.+?[jpeg|jpg|png])\"` на `"([^"]*\.(?:jpe?g|png))"`, [ошибка исчезнет](https://regex101.com/r/MT72Db/3), однако в некоторых случаях это выражение всё равно не сработает (разное количество пробельных символов, отсутствие или расположение в другом месте атрибута `target=\"_blank\"`).

Решение на основе `DOMDocument` представляется более уместным в таком случае.

[См. демо на PHP](https://3v4l.org/lEBZO):

```
$html = <<<EOD
<p>С этой формы приходят заявки <a href="https://site.com/lack_tech.php">https://site.com/lack_tech.php</a></p>
<p>Или что ты имеешь ввиду?</p>
<div class="attachment_files_message"> 
   <p>Прикреплённые файлы:</p>
   <a href="http://site.com/public/uploads/kylticket/2670/Screenshot_1.png" target="_blank">Screenshot_1.png</a>
</div>
EOD;

$dom = new DOMDocument();    // Создаем DOM
$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD); // Парсим DOM
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);         // Инициализируем структуру XPath на основе DOM    
foreach ($xpath->query('//a[@target="_blank"]') as $OurNode) {
    if (preg_match('~\.(?:jpe?g|png)$~i', $OurNode->getAttribute('href'))) {
        $fragment = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
        $aNode = $dom->createElement('a');
        $aNode->setAttribute('data-fancybox', 'gallery'); 
        $aNode->nodeValue = ''; 
        $aNode->setAttribute('href', $OurNode->getAttribute('href'));

        $img = $dom->createElement('img');
        $img->setAttribute("src", $OurNode->getAttribute('href'));
        $img->setAttribute("alt", "");
        $img->setAttribute("class", "tmp_class");
        $aNode->appendChild($img);
        $fragment->appendChild($aNode);
        $OurNode->parentNode->replaceChild($fragment, $OurNode);
    }
}
echo mb_convert_encoding($dom->saveHTML(), 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
```

Результат

```
<p>С этой формы приходят заявки <a href="https://site.com/lack_tech.php">https://site.com/lack_tech.php</a><p>Или что ты имеешь ввиду?</p><div class="attachment_files_message"> 
   <p>Прикреплённые файлы:</p>
   <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="http://site.com/public/uploads/kylticket/2670/Screenshot_1.png"><img src="http://site.com/public/uploads/kylticket/2670/Screenshot_1.png" alt="" class="tmp_class"></a>
</div></p>
```

В `foreach ($xpath->query('//a[@target="_blank"]') as $OurNode)` мы ищем все теги `a` с атрибутом `target` равным `_blank`. Далее мы проверяем, заканчивается ли значение атрибута `href` подстроками `.jpeg`, `.jpg` или `.png`, затем создаем новый тег `a`, добавляем к нему атрибуты, дочерний элемент `img` с атрибутами, а в конце заменяем старый тег `a` на новый.

Если и использовать тут регулярное выражение, стоит попробовать

```
preg_replace('~<a\s+((?:[^\s<>\'"=]+(?:=(?:"[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\'|[^\s\'">]+))?\s+)*)href=(?|"([^"]*\.(?:jpe?g|png))"|\'([^\']*\.(?:jpe?g|png))\'|([^\s\'">]*\.(?:jpe?g|png))(?=[>\s]))((?:\s+[^\s<>\'"=]+(?:=(?:"[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\'|[^\s\'">]+))?)*)\s*>(.*?)</a>~is', 
    '<a $1$3 data-fancybox="gallery" href="$2"><img src="$2" alt="" class="tmp_class"></a>',
    $row["message"])
```

[Демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/0WeF5K/5)

**Подробности**

- `<a` - подстрока `<a`
- `\s+` - 1+ пробельных символов
- `((?:[^\s<>'"=]+(?:=(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^\s'">]+))?\s+)*)` - захватывающая подмаска №1: 0 и более повторов атрибутов с опциональными значениями (т.е. может быть что-то типа `required`, `target='_blank'` и т.д.)
- `href=(?|"([^"]*\.(?:jpe?g|png))"|'([^']*\.(?:jpe?g|png))'|([^\s'">]*\.(?:jpe?g|png))(?=[>\s]))` - `=`, за которым следуют опциональные кавычки `'`/`"` и захватывающая подмаска №2, которая захватывает текст внутри `'...'` / `"..."` или символы, отличные от пробельных, `'`, `"` и `>`, если значение `href` заканчивается на `.` + `jpeg`, `jpg` или `png`
- `((?:\s+[^\s<>'"=]+(?:=(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^\s'">]+))?)*)` - захватывающая подмаска №3: 0 и более повторов атрибутов с опциональными значениями (т.е. может быть что-то типа `required`, target='_blank' и т.д.)
- `\s*>` - 0+ пробельных символов и `>`
- `(.*?)` - захватывающая подмаска №4: 0 и более любых символов до первого вхождения
- `</a>` - подстрока `</a>`.

Заменить совпадение нужно `<a $1$3 data-fancybox="gallery" href="$2"><img src="$2" alt="" class="tmp_class"></a>`, так как в захватывающих группах №1 и №3 могут быть дополнительные атрибуты.

[См. также PHP-демо](https://ideone.com/YllIHO):

```
$message = '<p>С этой формы приходят заявки <a href="https://site.com/lack_tech.php">https://site.com/lack_tech.php</a></p>
<p>Или что ты имеешь ввиду?</p>
<div class="attachment_files_message"> 
   <p>Прикреплённые файлы:</p>
   <a href="http://site.com/public/uploads/kylticket/2670/Screenshot_1.png" target="_blank">Screenshot_1.png</a>
</div>';
$message = preg_replace('~<a\s+((?:[^\s<>\'"=]+(?:=(?:"[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\'|[^\s\'">]+))?\s+)*)href=(?|"([^"]*\.(?:jpe?g|png))"|\'([^\']*\.(?:jpe?g|png))\'|([^\s\'">]*\.(?:jpe?g|png))(?=[>\s]))((?:\s+[^\s<>\'"=]+(?:=(?:"[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\'|[^\s\'">]+))?)*)\s*>(.*?)</a>~is', 
        '<a $1$3 data-fancybox="gallery" href="$2"><img src="$2" alt="" class="tmp_class"></a>',
        $message);
echo $message;
```

Результат

```
<p>С этой формы приходят заявки <a href="https://site.com/lack_tech.php">https://site.com/lack_tech.php</a></p>
<p>Или что ты имеешь ввиду?</p>
<div class="attachment_files_message"> 
   <p>Прикреплённые файлы:</p>
   <a  target="_blank" data-fancybox="gallery" href="http://site.com/public/uploads/kylticket/2670/Screenshot_1.png"><img src="http://site.com/public/uploads/kylticket/2670/Screenshot_1.png" alt="" class="tmp_class"></a>
</div>
```